# WSO2BAM Mediation Stats DB (hive not creating table in db)

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, cassandra, wso2, monitoring

Hello Guys I'm configuring WSO2ESB 4.8.1 and WSO2BAM 2.4.0 to see statistics, I'm sending data from ESB to BAM which is being stored in Cassandra, but the problem is when I deploy the Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring via BAM Toolbox then I see the following error in the console:

```
[2014-02-07 13:45:21,638] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  /var/www/formascloud/apps/wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/logs//wso2carbon.log
[2014-02-07 13:45:21,638] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
[2014-02-07 13:45:21,639] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
[2014-02-07 13:45:21,640] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.executeHiveQuery(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:569)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:282)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:189)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
[2014-02-07 13:45:21,641] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : esb_stats_296
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

[2014-02-07 13:45:21,443] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation} -  Failed to get total row count
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "mediation_stats_summary_per_minute" does not exist
  Position: 38
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.getTotalCount(DBOperation.java:335)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.input.JDBCSplit.getSplits(JDBCSplit.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.input.JDBCDataInputFormat.getSplits(JDBCDataInputFormat.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:925)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:792)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.getTotalCount(DBOperation.java:344)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.input.JDBCSplit.getSplits(JDBCSplit.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.input.JDBCDataInputFormat.getSplits(JDBCDataInputFormat.java:41)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:933)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:925)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:792)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1123)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:792)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:766)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:460)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:733)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

As you can see I'm using Postgresql, I created a db named BAM_STATS_DB, and this is the configuration stored in master-datasources.xml:

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE</name>
    <description>The datasource used for analyzer data</description>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>                             <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/BAM_STATS_DB</url>
                    <username>gregadmin</username>
                    <password>gregadmin</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                                <maxActive>80</maxActive>
                            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                                <validationQuery>select version();</validationQuery>
                             <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

What am I Doing wrong? I'm following the configuration from WSOBAM Docs.

Comment: Forgot to create the schema first? `"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "mediation_stats_summary_per_minute" does not exist` . Or case folding / quoting issues?

Comment: Tables are created from the Hive. So, pointing the WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE to a new database is okay

Comment: Hello as I said guys, the workaround was creating the tables directly in postgres, somehow the hive script didnt create it automatically, I'll keep searching to see what is going on with this. thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the BAM Toolbox doesn't support the PostgreSQL database.

The [BAM Toolbox](http://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Introduction+to+BAM+Toolbox) has following artifacts

1. Stream definitions
2. Analytics
3. Dashboard components

The Analytics has the hive scripts and those depend on underlying database used for the WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE

If you look at `wso2bam-2.4.0/samples/toolboxes`, you will see there multiple toolboxes depending on the database.

For example, the Mediation Statistics Monitoring toolbox has 3 different tbox files.

1. Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring_MSSQL.tbox
2. Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring_Oracle.tbox
3. Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring.tbox

If you install the toolbox via the Management Console UI, the default toolbox will be installed. In this case Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring.tbox.

This default toolbox works for few databases without any issue. For example MySQL.

You can simply edit the analytics scripts to work with PostgreSQL database.

You can unzip the toolbox (Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring.tbox) and edit `/Mediation_Statistics_Monitoring/analytics/esb_stats`

Fix all 'CREATE TABLE' SQLs used by JDBCStorageHandler.

Then create tbox archive again and copy to `wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/deployment/server/bam-toolbox`

Make sure to undeploy existing toolbox first.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your answers, the workaround for this problem was creating the tables direct via Pgadmin, of course there was a problem with the script since Postgresql does not accept Double data type, I changed it as Floast created the tables and everything is working now... maybe I am missing something in the configuration and thats why hive doesnt create the table automatically.

Comment: That's great! If you fix the toolbox, you could have used the hive script to create the tables

Comment: Hello Isuru despite I fixed the script for creating the table in Postgres It didnt work anyway via hive script... I had to created it via pgadmin...